# Large Dataset Searches In Elastic Search Via Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am starting to use Elastic Search for a project and a bit conflicted on how to go about searching. My impression was the real-time search is very fast and impressed with the speed of Kibana but I'm having a horrible time trying to find the best way to query large datasets (upwards of 5 million documents) via Java.

I have read online the best option is to use a Scroll search but it also states this is not intended for real-time search which makes sense when I see a query take upwards of 4 minutes to query 5 million documents (something that would be much faster via a SQL database). Can someone clarify if real-time search in ES is only fast when returning the top results but not when returning large datasets? I also need to clarification that Scroll search with QUERY AND FETCH makes the most sense for large queries, any other tips would be helpful.

Comment: why would you need to return large dataset for a query?

Comment: Good question, it is financial tick data being stored in Elastic Search and when doing back tests I need to query the entire data set for a market session.